# Don't let test stop on failure

Tags: junit, junit4

I'm looking for the best practice for following (simplified) scenario:

```java
@Test
public void someTest() {
  for(String someText : someTexts) {
    Assert.true(checkForValidity(someText));
  }
}
```

This test iterates through x-thousands of texts and in this case I don't want it to be stopped for each failure. I want the errors to be buffered and in case of error(s) to fail at the end. Has JUnit got something on board for for my aim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it's not really the correct way to implement this. JUnit allows [parametrizing](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) tests by defining a collection of inputs/outputs with the `Parametrized` test runner. Doing it this way ensures that each test case becomes a unique instance, making test report clearly state which samples passed and which ones failed.

If you still insist on doing it your way you should have a look at AssertJ's [Soft Assertions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#soft-assertions) which allow "swallowing" individual assertion failures, accumulating them and only reporting after the test is finished. The linked documentation section uses a nice example and is definitely worth reading.

Comment: Nice pointing out a best practice way and one "comfortable" solution.

Comment: JUnit itself provides soft assertions with the [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule.